# Solr delete using negated field not working

Tags: solr

I'm trying to delete old records which don't have field indexDate present. I am using post.jar which commits by default. The delete post is not removing the records.

Calling this does not work:
java -Ddata=args -jar post.jar "-indexDate:*"

Any ideas?

---

Update
I don't think this is currently possible in Solr. In addition to trying post.jar and direct http access, I attempted to do a delete based on negative field presence query -- all did not work. I ended up doing a search for all records without the field, then explicitly deleting each result.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend deleting via a [Delete Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query) to your Solr instance. So you would do something similar to the following for your case of deleting where records do not have an indexDate specified:

```
 curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" 
    --data-binary '<update><delete><query>-indexDate:*</query></delete></update>';
```

Comment: I tried the given curl call, with small modification (missing initial update tag). Unfortunately it didn't help.
Response:
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">306</int></lst>
</response>

Comment: I fixed the missing initial update tag, thank you for pointing that out... Can you verify that the `-indexDate:*` query is returning the expected records you want to remove?(e.g. run that query in the admin interface at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/)

Comment: Yes, the -indexDate:* query returns the expected results (records without indexDate field)

Comment: Not sure then, as this should work. Maybe make sure you have the commit=true option set in your url, as the records will be actually removed from the index until a commit is executed.